# CLOC ignore/exclude list file (.clocignore)

Tags: shell, cloc

(*Edit: see **Proper Usage** section on the bottom.*)

**Main Question**

How do you get [`cloc`](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) to use its `--exclude-list-file=<file>` option?  Essentially, I'm trying to feed it a `.clocignore` file.

**Expected Behavior**

`cloc` documentation says the following:

```
--exclude-list-file=<file>  Ignore files and/or directories whose names
                          appear in <file>.  <file> should have one entry
                          per line.  Relative path names will be resolved
                          starting from the directory where cloc is
                          invoked.  See also --list-file.
```

**Attempts**

The following command works as expected:

```
cloc --exclude-dir=node_modules .
```

But this command doesn't exclude anything:

```
cloc --exclude-list-file=myignorefile .
```

This is the contents of `myignorefile`:

```
node_modules
node_modules/
node_modules/*
node_modules/**
./node_modules
./node_modules/
./node_modules/*
./node_modules/**
/full/path/to/current/directory/node_modules
/full/path/to/current/directory/node_modules/
/full/path/to/current/directory/node_modules/*
/full/path/to/current/directory/node_modules/**
```

`cloc` does *not* error if `myignorefile` doesn't exist, so I have no feedback on what it's doing.

(I'm running OS X and installed `cloc` v1.60 via Homebrew.)

---

---

### Proper Usage

*tl;dr* -- The method specified in @Raman's answer both requires less to be specified in `.clocignore` and runs considerably faster.

---

Spurred on by @Raman's answer, I investigated the source code: `cloc` *does* in fact respect `--exclude-list-file` but processes it differently than `--exclude-dir` in two important ways.

#### Exact filename versus 'part of the path'

First, while `--exclude-dir` will ignore any files whose paths contain the specified strings, `--exclude-list-file` will only exclude the exact files or directories specified in `.clocignore`.

If you have a **directory structure** like this:

```
.clocignore
node_modules/foo/first.js
app/node_modules/bar/second.js
```

And the contents of `.clocignore` is just

```
node_modules
```

Then `cloc --exclude-list-file=.clocignore .` will successfully ignore `first.js` but count `second.js`.  Whereas `cloc --exclude-dir=node_modules .` will ignore both.

To deal with this, `.clocignore` needs to contain this:

```
node_modules
app/node_modules
```

#### Performance

Second, the source code for `cloc` appears to add the directories specified in `--exlude-dir` to a list which is consulted *before* counting the files.  Whereas the list of directories discovered by `--exclude-list-file` is consulted *after* counting the files.

Meaning, `--exclude-list-file` still processes the files, which can be slow, before ignoring their results in the final report.  This is borne out by experiment: in an example codebase, it took half a second to run `cloc` with `--exclude-dir`, and 11 seconds to run with an equivalent `--exclude-list-file`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best workaround I've found is to feed the contents of `.clocignore` directly to `--exclude-dir`. For example, if you are using `bash` and have `tr` available:

```
cloc --exclude-dir=$(tr '\n' ',' < .clocignore) .
```

Comment: `exclude-list-file` wasn't working for me in the same way as `exlude-dir`, but I didn't spend any time figuring out why. You could take a look at the source here: http://sourceforge.net/p/cloc/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/cloc

Comment: Thanks.  I expanded on why it doesn't appear to work in the Question.  Hopefully, it makes sense now.

Comment: Great, thanks for the investigation! It's too bad `--exclude-list-file` doesn't work as one would expect.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, since I wanted to specify sub-directories as well, which is only possible by using the `--not-match-d=""` regex argument. So I created a PHP file that generates the whole CLOC command using the .clocignore file (Example output)

```
$ php cloc.php

cloc --fullpath --not-match-d="(node_modules|App/ios|App/android)" --not-match-f="(yarn\.lock|package\.json|package\-lock\.json)" .
```

The script basically implodes the directory paths as a single regex string and outputs the full cloc command for copying convenience. I put it up on gist if anyone finds it useful :)

https://gist.github.com/Lukakva/a2ef7626724a809ff2859e7203accf53

Answer (score 3):

`--not-match-d` and `--not-match-f` may also meet your need.

> ```
>    --not-match-d=REGEX
>        Count all files except in directories matching the Perl regex.  Only the trailing directory name is compared, for example, when counting in
>        "/usr/local/lib", only "lib" is compared to the regex.  Add --fullpath to compare parent directories to the regex.  Do not include file path
>        separators at the beginning or end of the regex.
>
>   --match-f=REGEX
>        Only count files whose basenames match the Perl regex. For example this only counts files at start with Widget or widget:
>
>            --match-f='^[Ww]idget'
>
>        Add --fullpath to include parent directories in the regex instead of just the basename.
>
>   --not-match-f=REGEX
>        Count all files except those whose basenames match the Perl regex.  Add --fullpath to include parent directories in the regex instead of just the
>        basename.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works for my project [image]

I installed cloc and added script for it, like so:

```
   "cloc-src": "cloc --exclude-dir=node_modules,dist,mongo-data-4.4,yarn.lock,package.json,package-lock.json .",
   "cloc-dist": "cloc --match-d=/dist/ .",
```